# How to determine the URL that a local Git repository was originally cloned from

Tags: git, github, git-remote

I pulled a project with several forks on GitHub, but forgot which fork it was. How do I determine which fork I pulled?

Comment: With git 2.7 (Q4 2015), `git remote get-url origin` will be possible. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32991784/6309)

Comment: `git remote get-url origin` does not work for me--possibly deprecated? `git remote show origin` worked though.

Comment: `git remote -v` give you a lot of information, including this.

Comment: `git remote get-url origin --push` works fine, apparently not depreciated and provides nice brief info (`git remote show origin` can be _very_ verbose) q.v. `git help remote`.

Answer (score 7591, accepted):

To obtain only the remote URL:

```
git config --get remote.origin.url
```

If you require full output, and you are on a network that can reach the remote repo where the origin resides:

```
git remote show origin
```

When using `git clone` (from GitHub, or any source repository for that matter) the default name for the source of the clone is "origin". Using `git remote show` will display the information about this remote name. The first few lines should show:

```
C:\Users\jaredpar\VsVim> git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: git@github.com:jaredpar/VsVim.git
  Push  URL: git@github.com:jaredpar/VsVim.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
```

If you want to use the value in a script, you would use the first command listed in this answer.

Comment: Use git config as described below instead if using jgit with amazon-s3.

Comment: Although not relevant to the purpose of the original question, please note that if attempting to get the "Push URL" and multiple URLs are entered for the remote specified, you'll either need to use `git remote show origin` (optionally with the -n flag provided by @Casey), or with `git remote -v` as suggested by @Montaro and @rodel.

Comment: What file is this written to?  I thought the `.gitconfig` file would have it, but I didn't see it in mine.

Comment: @ayjay `´~/.gitconfig` is global to all `git` repositories, this here comes from the local config which usually is in `.git/config` (however for git-submodules the answer is a bit more difficult).  Note that `strace git config --get remote.origin.url` is your friend.

Comment: But the original URL doesn't have to be the URL of the currently used remote. To show the actual used URL, you would need this solution then: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40630957/1069083

Comment: Note: the approach `git remote show origin` doesn't work if the stored credentials do no longer have required access rights to the original repository. In such case, try `git remote -v`

Comment: I removed the phrase "referential integrity" as it is misleading in the context of git. Searching the git docs for the phrase reveals no hits https://git-scm.com/search/results?search=referential%20integrity  The first command works when you are offline and the second works only if you are online.

Comment: git config --get remote.origin.url this works for me

Comment: Also `git config --get remote.origin.url` will not error out if the directory does not have a initialised repository and instead returns nothing (empty string)

Comment: Shallow copy of git doesn't give any result for this.

Comment: As mentioned in the @CarlSuster's answer below, use `ls-remote` instead. This does not work with `insteadof` properly.

Answer (score 775):

This gives only the URL, which is useful for scripting purposes:

```
git config --get remote.origin.url
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. It is way faster and it even works, if the remote url is not available anymore (`git remote show origin` just shows "conq: repository does not exist.").

Comment: This is not quite the right answer because of the config option `url.<base>.insteadOf`. See my answer - git has a command for this purpose.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq I don't really care in this case, but in general please avoid purely stylistic edits - authors are free to write in their preferred style as long as it's clear.

Comment: TO CHANGE THIS, do: **`git remote set-url origin http://.....  `**
OR, look here: [https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/managing-remote-repositories] for more directions.
And, upvote this comment since it's probably what a bunch of people want to do

Answer (score 766):

This will print all your remotes' fetch/push URLs:

```
git remote -v
```

Comment: @Montaro exactly, without it, only the name of the remote is printed (e.g. `origin`).

Answer (score 323):

To get the answer:

```
git ls-remote --get-url [REMOTE]
```

This is better than reading the configuration; refer to the [man page for `git-ls-remote`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote.html):

> **--get-url**
>
> Expand the URL of the given remote repository taking into account
>   any `"url.<base>.insteadOf"` config setting (See `git-config(1)`) and
>   exit without talking to the remote.

As pointed out by @Jefromi, this option was added in [v1.7.5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/45781adb9a89c0c47f61ccf8062be26b86a38a54) and not documented until [v1.7.12.2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2303cad242a6ccc4745d7994ecc0425bd8513a0d) (2012-09).

Comment: good one :
this also would provide the same for previous versions
     > git remote -v| grep fetch|awk '{print $2}'

Comment: I think most of the other answers are more of a show-and-tell about git commands and exposition about git history. This is the only answer that doesn't assume your upstream is called `origin`.

Comment: This is the most direct replacement for the old ``remote get-url`` option. It's a drop-in replacement.

Answer (score 168):

With Git 2.7 (release January 5th, 2015), you have a more coherent solution using `git remote`:

```
git remote get-url origin
```

(nice pendant of `git remote set-url origin <newurl>`)

See [commit 96f78d3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/96f78d39989d1fcf393d7bc42357467dd8cf0f15) (16 Sep 2015) by [Ben Boeckel (`mathstuf`)](https://github.com/mathstuf).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit e437cbd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e437cbd01564f0c31fad068fa1f88feea5d806da), 05 Oct 2015)</sup>:

> ## remote: add get-url subcommand
>
> Expanding `insteadOf` is a part of `ls-remote --url` and there is no way
>   to expand `pushInsteadOf` as well.
>   Add a `get-url` subcommand to be able to query both as well as a way to get all configured URLs.

```
get-url:
```

> Retrieves the URLs for a remote.
>   Configurations for `insteadOf` and `pushInsteadOf` are expanded here.
>   By default, only the first URL is listed.
>
> - With '`--push`', push URLs are queried rather than fetch URLs.
> - With '`--all`', all URLs for the remote will be listed.

---

Before git 2.7, you had:

```
 git config --get remote.[REMOTE].url
 git ls-remote --get-url [REMOTE]
 git remote show [REMOTE]
```

Answer (score 147):

#### To summarize, there are at least four ways:

Trying it out using the official Linux repository:

#### Least information:

```
$ git config --get remote.origin.url
https://github.com/torvalds/linux.git
```

and

```
$ git ls-remote --get-url
https://github.com/torvalds/linux.git
```

#### More information:

```
$ git remote -v
origin    https://github.com/torvalds/linux.git (fetch)
origin    https://github.com/torvalds/linux.git (push)
```

#### Even more information:

```
$ git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: https://github.com/torvalds/linux.git
  Push  URL: https://github.com/torvalds/linux.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branch:
    master tracked
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    master merges with remote master
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (up to date)
```

Comment: Note `git config --get remote.origin.url` retrieves the original URL which was set with `git remote add ...` or `git remote set-url ...` while `git ls-remote --get-url origin` retrieves the URL which is actually used to access the remote - which might be different in presence of `git config --global url.XXX.insteadOf YYY`.  **So both outputs may differ!**  Also note that `git ls-remote --get-url` (without `origin`) does not neccessarily retrieve `origin`, instead it shows the tracked upstream, so it will fail for example in detached HEAD state.

Comment: No longer supported

Answer (score 45):

For me, this is the easier way (less typing):

```
git remote -v
```

Output:

```
origin    https://github.com/torvalds/linux.git (fetch)
origin    https://github.com/torvalds/linux.git (push)
```

Actually, I've that into an `alias` called `s` that does:

```
git remote -v
git status
```

You can add to your profile with:

`alias s='git remote -v && git status'`

Answer (score 32):

I think you can find it under `.git/config` and `remote["origin"]` if you didn't manipulate that.

Answer (score 28):

Short answer:

```
$ git remote show -n origin
```

or, an alternative for pure quick scripts:

```
$ git config --get remote.origin.url
```

Some info:

1. `$ git remote -v` will print all remotes (not what you want). You want origin right?
2. `$ git remote show origin` much better, shows only `origin` but takes too long (tested on git version 1.8.1.msysgit.1).

I ended up with: `$ git remote show -n origin`, which  seems to be fastest. With `-n` it will not fetch remote heads (AKA branches). You don't need that type of info, right?

http://www.kernel.org/pub//software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html

You can apply `| grep -i fetch` to all three versions to show only the fetch URL.

If you require pure speed, then use:

```
$ git config --get remote.origin.url
```

Thanks to [@Jefromi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4090938/2098832) for pointing that out.

Answer (score 21):

The Git URL will be inside the Git configuration file. The value corresponds to the key `url`.

For Mac and Linux, use the commands below:

```
awk '/url/{print $3}' project_dir/.git/config
```

For Windows, open the below file in any text editor and find the value for key `url`.

```
project_dir/.git/config
```

Note: This will work even if you are offline or the remote Git server has been taken down.

Comment: This is what worked for me once the remote server that hosted the original checkout was taken down. All the other attempts failed: `git remote get-url origin >> fatal: No such remote 'origin'`, `git config --get remote.origin.url >>`

Answer (score 21):

I can never remember all the parameters to Git commands, so I just put an alias in the `~/.gitconfig` file that makes more sense to me, so I can remember it, and it results in less typing:

```
[alias]
url = ls-remote --get-url
```

After reloading the terminal, you can then just type:

```
> git url
```

Here are a few more of my frequently used ones:

```
[alias]
cd = checkout
ls = branch
lsr = branch --remote
lst = describe --tags
```

I also highly recommend [git-extras](https://github.com/tj/git-extras) which has a `git info` [command](https://github.com/tj/git-extras/blob/master/Commands.md#git-info) which provides much more detailed information on the remote and local branches.

Comment: Nice aliases, I love how they meld very naturally with `bash` commands. I can see this being causing the least amount of mental friction when switching between `bash` and `git`. Bravo!

Answer (score 20):

I prefer this one as it is easier to remember:

```
git config -l
```

It will list all useful information such as:

```
user.name=Your Name
user.email=your.name@notexisting.com
core.autocrlf=input
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
remote.origin.url=https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
```

Answer (score 17):

I basically use:

```
git remote get-url origin
```

It works for Git Bash command console or CMD command console in Windows. That said, it works with version 2.x of Git.

Answer (score 16):

The upstream's remote may not be called "origin", so here's a variation:

```
remote=$(git config --get branch.master.remote)
url=$(git config --get remote.$remote.url)
basename=$(basename "$url" .git)
echo $basename
```

Or:

```
basename $(git config --get remote.$(git config --get branch.master.remote).url) .git
```

For more useful variables there's:

```
$ git config -l
```

Answer (score 15):

```
git config --list
```

This command will give all information related to your repository.

Answer (score 14):

A simple way is to open the `.git/config` file:

```
cat .git/config
```

To edit:

`vim .git/config` or

`nano .git/config`

Comment: This presumes you are on Linux(?).

Answer (score 13):

You cloned your repository with SSH clone.

```
git config --get remote.origin.url
git@gitlab.com:company/product/production.git
```

But you want to get an HTTP URL to open it in the browser or share it:

```
git config --get remote.origin.url | sed -e 's/:/\//g'| sed -e 's/ssh\/\/\///g'| sed -e 's/git@/https:\/\//g'

https://gitlab.com/company/product/production.git
```

GitHub or GitLab doesn’t matter.

Comment: Useful! Doesn't work on https urls though. This one is universal, works for both `git@...` and `https://...`: `git config --get remote.origin.url | sed -E 's/:([^\/])/\/\1/g' | sed -e 's/ssh\/\/\///g' | sed -e 's/git@/https:\/\//g'`

Comment: I modified it to support HTTPS, SSH and remove the **.git** suffix from the URL: `git config --get remote.origin.url | sed -E 's/git@(.*?)\:/http:\/\/\1/;s/\.git$//'`

Answer (score 12):

Print arbitrarily named remote fetch URLs:

```
git remote -v | grep fetch | awk '{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 10):

#### To get the IP address/hostname of `origin`

For `ssh://` repositories:

```
git ls-remote --get-url origin | cut -f 2 -d @ | cut -f 1 -d "/"
```

For `git://` repositories:

```
git ls-remote --get-url origin | cut -f 2 -d @ | cut -f 1 -d ":"
```

Comment: For `ssh` this only works in absence of `~/.ssh/config` which rewrites the hostname or alias.

Answer (score 10):

To supplement the other answers:  If the remote has for some reason been changed and so doesn't reflect the *original* origin, the very first entry in the reflog (i.e. the last entry displayed by the command `git reflog`) should indicate where the repo was originally cloned from.

e.g.

```
$ git reflog | tail -n 1
f34be46 HEAD@{0}: clone: from https://github.com/git/git
$
```

(Bear in mind that the reflog may be purged, so this isn't guaranteed to work.)

Answer (score 9):

With `git remote show origin` you have to be in the projects directory. But if you want to determine the URLs from anywhere else
you could use:

```
cat <path2project>/.git/config | grep url
```

If you'll need this command often, you could define an alias in your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` with MacOS.

```
alias giturl='cat ./.git/config | grep url'
```

So you just need to call `giturl` in the Git root folder in order to simply obtain its URL.

---

If you extend this alias like this

```
alias giturl='cat .git/config | grep -i url | cut -d'=' -f 2'
```

you get only the plain URL without the preceding

> "url="

in

> url=http://example.com/repo.git

you get more possibilities in its usage:

**Example**

On Mac you could call `open $(giturl)` to open the URL in the standard browser.

Or `chrome $(giturl)` to open it with the Chrome browser on Linux.

Answer (score 7):

If you do not know the name of the upstream remote for a branch, you can look that up first by inspecting the upstream branch name that the current branch was built upon. Use `git rev-parse` like this:

```
git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name --abbrev-ref @{upstream}
```

This shows that upstream branch that was the source for the current branch. This can be parsed to get the remote name like this:

```
git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name --abbrev-ref @{upstream} | cut -d / -f 1
```

Now take that and pipe it to `git ls-remote` and you'll get the URL of the upstream remote that is the source of the current branch:

```
git ls-remote --get-url \
  $(git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name --abbrev-ref @{upstream} | cut -d / -f 1)
```

Now it should be noted, that this is not necessarily the same as the source remote repository that was cloned from. In many cases however it will be enough.

Answer (score 6):

```
#!/bin/bash

git-remote-url() {
 local rmt=$1; shift || { printf "Usage: git-remote-url [REMOTE]\n" >&2; return 1; }
 local url

 if ! git config --get remote.${rmt}.url &>/dev/null; then
  printf "%s\n" "Error: not a valid remote name" && return 1
  # Verify remote using 'git remote -v' command
 fi

 url=`git config --get remote.${rmt}.url`

 # Parse remote if local clone used SSH checkout
 [[ "$url" == git@* ]] \
 && { url="https://github.com/${url##*:}" >&2; }; \
 { url="${url%%.git}" >&2; };

 printf "%s\n" "$url"
}
```

Usage:

```
# Either launch a new terminal and copy `git-remote-url` into the current shell process, 
# or create a shell script and add it to the PATH to enable command invocation with bash.

# Create a local clone of your repo with SSH, or HTTPS
git clone git@github.com:your-username/your-repository.git
cd your-repository

git-remote-url origin
```

Output:

```
https://github.com/your-username/your-repository
```

Answer (score 6):

To get only the remote URL:

```
git config --get remote.origin.url
```

In order to get more details about a particular remote, use the

```
git remote show [remote-name] command
```

To see the remote URL:

```
git remote show origin
```

To see where you .git folder placed:

```
git config --get remote.origin.url
```

Answer (score 3):

```bash
alias git-repo="git config --get remote.origin.url | sed -e 's/:/\//g'| sed -e 's/ssh\/\/\///g'| sed -e 's/git@/https:\/\//g'"
alias git-pr="git config --get remote.origin.url | sed -e 's/:/\//g'| sed -e 's/ssh\/\/\///g'| sed -e 's/git@/https:\/\//g' | sed 's/....$//' | sed -ne 's/$/\/pulls &/p'"
```

Add this expression to the [.zshrc](https://wiki.debian.org/Zsh#Configuration) or [.bashrc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)#Legacy-compatible_Bash_startup_example)  file in the main directory.

After that, you can use like

```bash
git-repo
git-pr
```

Answer (score 2):

My favorite is this (only works for *public* repositories).

1. Check the pattern
2. Check that a web request returns a valid GitHub repository.

   ```py
   import re
   import requests

   def is_github_repo(url):
       pattern = re.compile(r'^https://github\.com/[^/]+/[^/]+$')
       if not pattern.match(url):
           return False
       response = requests.head(url)
       return response.status_code == 200 and \
              response.headers['Content-Type'].startswith('text/html')

   url = 'https://github.com/username/repo-name'
   if is_github_repo(url):
       print(f'{url} is a GitHub repository.')
   else:
       print(f'{url} is not a GitHub repository.')
   ```

Comment: Note: In the interactive Python shell, [the empty line in the middle of function `is_github_repo()` will result in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727988/python-indentation-in-empty-lines/2728019#2728019) `IndentationError: unexpected indent`