# How can I retrieve the remote Git address of a repository?

Tags: git

How can I retrieve the remote Git address of a repository?

I tried `git remote`, but that just lists the branches.

Comment: This is `git remote -v`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I determine the url that a local git repo was originally cloned from?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089430/how-can-i-determine-the-url-that-a-local-git-repo-was-originally-cloned-from)

Answer (score 341):

When you want to show an URL of remote branches, try:

```
git remote -v
```

Comment: But this shows all remotes, origin and others, how do I retrieve only the one, where I am on a branch?

Comment: maybe what you need is `git remote get-url remote-name`

Answer (score 89):

If you have the name of the remote, you will be able with git 2.7 (Q4 2015), to use the new `git remote get-url` command:

```
git remote get-url origin
```

(nice pendant of `git remote set-url origin <newurl>`)

See [commit 96f78d3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/96f78d39989d1fcf393d7bc42357467dd8cf0f15) (16 Sep 2015) by [Ben Boeckel (`mathstuf`)](https://github.com/mathstuf).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit e437cbd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e437cbd01564f0c31fad068fa1f88feea5d806da), 05 Oct 2015)</sup>

> ## remote: add get-url subcommand
>
> Expanding `insteadOf` is a part of `ls-remote --url` and there is no way
>   to expand `pushInsteadOf` as well.
>   Add a `get-url` subcommand to be able to query both as well as a way to get all configured urls.

Answer (score 2):

The long boring solution, which is not involved with CLI, you can manually navigate to:

your local repo *folder* ➡ .git *folder* (hidden) ➡ config *file*

then choose your text editor to open it and look for url located under the [remote "origin"] section.

Answer (score 2):

-v. Shows URLs of remote repositories when listing your current remote connections. By default, listing remote repositories only shows you their shortnames (e.g. "origin"). Using the "-v" option, you will also see the remote's URLs in listings.

```
git remote -v
```