# How can I determine the url of a git server, inside of a git project?

Tags: git

I need only the server part, for example, if my project is on `git@192.168.1.1:project.git`, I want `git@192.168.1.1`

Thanks,

Comment: If you just want to use git for that, have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089430/how-can-i-determine-the-url-that-a-local-git-repo-was-originally-cloned-from).

Comment: Note a machine might have more than one ip

Comment: Ummm....git is a **distributed** version control system, so there is no such thing as a single authoritative server for a given repo.

Comment: @jack: but you may have a remote branch on which you local branch tracks changes. I think it's fair to assume, that he talks about that remote. If such a remote branch is not given... well, then you don't know which URL to look for.

Comment: @eaglebh which platform/programming languages is/are available for your solution? Having python, ruby or something better than bash, would definitely help. This may we might even be able to avoid regexes ;)

Comment: Jack: I know that, but on this case we have just one server, that have one address when accessed from internal network, and other when accessed externaly.
Philipp: I'm on Windows and Linux, but on Windows I still have bash with Git Bash.
@all: thanks for the help, with all the info and some bash skills I got it done now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a url, you just [parse the url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27745/getting-parts-of-a-url-regex).

Here's [how to find the url of one of your own repo's remotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089430/how-can-i-determine-the-url-that-a-local-git-repo-was-originally-cloned-from?lq=1)

If you mean you want to find "the" url for your own repo, that won't work. It all depends on whether or not somebody's fired up *a* server at a particular address; nothing says there can't be multiples -- and you can use 'file:' urls without any server at all.

Comment: Thanks. Using that with the command below I could get what I wanted:

Comment: repodir=`git rev-parse --show-toplevel`  
    myself=`basename $repodir`  
    urlbase=`git config --get remote.origin.url|sed "s/$myself\.git//"`

Answer (score 3):

The following bash command gives you the server part for the remote called `origin`:

```
echo `git config --get "remote.origin.url"` | sed "s|\([^:]*\):.*|\1|"
```

If you are not sure if the remote for the current branch is always called origin, you may execute the following to find the remote of the current branch:

```
git config --get "branch.master.remote"
```

Comment: I admit, that the regex needs some work. It probably does not work with URLs containing colons (IPv6, user:pass@server.com, ...). Any ideas for a better regex appreciated :)

Comment: The problem with this happens when we have for example:  ssh://git@192.16.10.3:2222/project.git