# How to find a url for a local GIT repo

Tags: git

In our Development environment, I can see that the GIT repository was cloned from TEST,

In the config file,

```
[remote "origin"]
   url = //foo/test-foo-project
   fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

I now want to pull the repository in Development, to my local instance. I know //foo/test-foo-project isn't a real path.. But I can determine which URL to use?

Comment: You can't really do this with Git. As Git is decentralised, repositories only store locations of "remotes", other repos they're somehow connected to, like they one they were cloned from. They don't track the entire network of repositories. Clone your local repo from wherever you intend to push changes, and add whichever other remotes you with. If you don't need to push changes, you can clone the DEV one directly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I determine the url that a local git repo was originally cloned from?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089430/how-can-i-determine-the-url-that-a-local-git-repo-was-originally-cloned-from)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Git command that could get you the `url` from `origin`

> $git config --get remote.origin.url

But you would not be able to set a new path

> $git config remote.origin.url "newPath"

This would fail with the message error: `could not lock config file ./config: File exists`

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thanks. +1

Comment: when i run this command i received a not working url:
ssh://[username]@[replica.url]:29418/[project_name]

Answer (score 2):

In your home directory do `less .shh/config` then you can see the URL for `foo`.

If it is not there you can try `git remote show` and then probably `git remote show origin`.

Do you remember how you cloned this repo, can you past the command here?

Answer (score -2):

Simply you can find a url for a local GIT repo by `giturl` command.

```
$ gem install giturl
$ giturl .
https://*****/
```