# Locate Visual Studio Team Services url in visual studio solution

Tags: visual-studio-2013, azure-devops

Somewhere in visual studio I have set the url for my solution to connect to Visual Studio Team Services but for the life of me I cant  find it.

When you create a new project and want to sync it with the TFS server you are presented with a dialog as below:

[image]

I have already completed this step for existing solutions but where do I "read" that setting?
It seems to have disappeared? Is it in the registry?

Comment: You could read this from the command line using the "git remote" command I believe.

Comment: @AndrewClear ok thanks for the pointer. As a result I have found numerous howtos: on this subject

Answer (score 1):

As per Andrews comment I have confirmed that it is possible to get the url of a Visual Studio Team Services project by opening the Package Management Console (PMC) and running the following command

git config --get remote.origin.url

References:

[How can I determine the URL that a local Git repository was originally cloned from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089430/how-can-i-determine-the-url-that-a-local-git-repo-was-originally-cloned-from)

[Change the URI (URL) for a remote Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432764/change-the-uri-url-for-a-remote-git-repository)