# How do you get full url of branch to clone from command line? Bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have cloned development once before and I see it under

```
 git branch -a
```

Now I want to do a fresh clone from another directory but I cannot git clone 'development'

How do I get the full clone url from the command line? I could use the bitbucket UI but I would like to be able to grab the url from command line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I determine the URL that a local Git repository was originally cloned from?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089430/how-can-i-determine-the-url-that-a-local-git-repository-was-originally-cloned-fr)

Answer (score 1):

First, you can get the irl with git config --get remote.origin.url, which means, from another directory, you can type:

```
git clone $(git -C /path/to/first/local/clone config --get remote.origin.url)
```

You can add `-b development` if you want that second clone to directly clone the right branch.

Second, you don't have to re-clone everything: with the command [`git worktree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree), you can have in another directory a *second* worktree based on another branch.
See more at "[Multiple working directories with Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30185564/6309)".