# Finding Github url for code in a cloned project

Tags: git, github

I am doing some large scale analysis of Java projects on Github; this involves cloning the project via git (nothing special here), then doing a static read of the code for analysis, and so on.

My question: is there a way to programmatically recover the Github url for each source file in the cloned repository? I'm trying to get this so I can then link back into Github and see the original source.

For example, the following url (what I want): https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/libs/elasticsearch-nio/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/nio/BytesWriteOperation.java#L35 points to a particular function. Of course, the directory structure in the cloned version doesn't match the url name, e.g., the /blob/master/ seems particular to this project and structure of the repository.

Comment: You may want to look at the `raw` version of the particular file. It should start with `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/something`

Comment: You can get the github url for cloned repository. https://stackoverflow.com/a/4089452/1562662

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I'm understanding correctly you want to create a link to a human readable code view with a specific line highlighted.

Essentially the normal GitHub link breaks down into:

1. URL to the User Repo e.g. `https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch` (aka the remote origin)
2. `/blob/`
3. the path to the file ***within the repo***, which should be identical to the local repo you just cloned.

Each of these components are pretty simple to get.

**1. Remote Origin**
*(aka <remote-origin>)*

When you clone a repo, the local copy you create stores a reference to the remote origin URL.

```
$ git config --get remote.origin.url

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch
```

*or*, for more detail:

```
$ git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch
  Push  URL: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch
  HEAD branch: develop
  Remote branches:
    1.4                    new (next fetch will store in remotes/origin)
    2.0                    tracked
    add-code-of-conduct-1  tracked
    build_test             tracked
    ...
```

*and so on*

**2. Branch**
*(aka <branch>)*

You're no doubt aware of how to get the repo's branches:

```
git branch
  develop
* master
```

but you can also use `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` to return just the current branch.

```
git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
master
```

From those pieces of information and the file path within the local copy of the repo you can build the link

```
<remote-origin>/blob/<branch>/<path-to-file-in-repo>#L<line_number>
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested you can use githubusercontent:
Syntax should be:

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/<user>/<repo>/<branch>/<file>
```

Comment: thanks for the pointer! That's quite useful as a first step, but is there a way to then link back to the non raw file on Github?