# git status working directory nothing to commit, working directory to clean, add , commit NO GO

Tags: github

---I have the same problem but the fix does not seem to work.

I cloned a new repository.  From it, I
a. created a new branch with `git checkout -b`
b. We updated our files in one of the directories, call it `GAWBE`
c. did our push to that branch
d. inspected the branch on the github.com site,  It was fine

Then, I had to update files in a different directory to the master branch.
Call the directory PDBE
Thus, I did

1. git checkout master
2. went to the `PDBE` directory
3. updated several files there
4. did the git status
   (I got the message

   ## On branch master

   `nothing to commit, working directory clean`
   as indicated above)
5. I did the `git branch --set-upstream-to origin/master`
   Got the message
   `Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.`
   f. I then did git status
   Again, I got
   `# On branch master
   nothing to commit, working directory clean`
6. I tried 
   `git pull origin`

   `From https://github.com/doctorleff/u3e
   *branch master -> FETCH_HEAD
   Already up to date.`

   h. I tried `git status` again with the same `working directoyr clean` message
   and `git commit` with the same message

Needless to say, I alo checked my `.gitignore` and `.git/info/exclude`
Nothing in the latter--former does not specify any of the files in question,
all .java

This as per the Issue 37269222
Also tried the rm -rf .git  (Issue 37900326)
also tried git log as per issue 29578546, got error message:
fatal: bad default revision 'HEAD'

---

Thank you for suggesting that I create a minimal file to show the problem
with my branches and git hub.

On github, I created a new repository.   (It is marked public.)
(It  is `doctorleff/TR`

1) I created a directory `TR` to serve as my repository.
2) I put a single file there `IncomeFile.java` 
3)  `git init`
Told me `Initialized empty Git repository in /home/leffstudent/TR/.git`
4) `git add IncomeFile.java`
5) Created `gitignore` with `*.class`
6) `git add .gitignore`
7) `git status` told me

```
# On branch master
# 
# Initial commit
#
# Changes to be committed:
#    (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
#
#        new file: .gitignore
#        new file: IncomeFile.java
8) `git commit -m "first commit"
```

Response was:

```
[master (root-commit) 6e71c52] first commit
 2 files changed, 37 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 .gitignore
 create mode 100644 IncomeFile.java
```

8) `git remote add origin https:/github.com/doctorleff/TR.git`
9) git push -u origin master
It asked me for my git login and password, then told me

```
Counting ojbects: 4, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 681 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
```

10) `git checkout -b TOMCAT`
Told me:
`Switched to a new branch 'TOMCAT'`
11) I changed `IncomeFile.java` slightly
12) git add IncomeFile.java
13) git commit -m "testing tomcat branch"

```
[TOMCAT 54f1b57] testing tomcat branch
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion (-)
```

14) `git push origin tomcat`
Again, I was asked for my github username and passwrd.

Then it told me:

```
error: src refspect tomcat does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/doctorleff/TR.git'
```

15) When I did a `git status`

```
$On branch TOMCAT
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Same thing if I simply type `git status`

I tried `git check-ignore -v -- IncomeFile.java`
Just get back the prompt

---

My test directory now seems to be working.  Thus, I went back to the original cloned repository about which I spoke earlier.

I followed some of the instructions in
StackOverflow issue 4089430.   (See link below)
I compared the results on both the working TEST repository and the 
repository that does not work. It appears that the local repository
lost track of its remote.

I was thinking, should I do a git clone right into the defective 
repositories to reconnect them to the world.

Meanwhile, I worked around my problem by cloning to a different computer, 
a Macintosh.  I am able to work normally with
the remote repository.  Thus, I don't believe there is any problem with it.
And I have, a slightly less convenient, way to proceed with our project.

[[How can I determine the URL that a local Git repository was originally cloned from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089430/how-can-i-determine-the-url-that-a-local-git-repository-was-originally-cloned-fr])

I have two transcripts (edited slightly from script). The first is from
the test repository, that shows things working--
thanks for asking me to try that--

and then from the real one

```
cd TR
git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: https://github.com/doctorleff/TR.git
  Push  URL: https://github.com/doctorleff/TR.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
    TOMCAT tracked
    master tracked
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    master merges with remote master
  Local refs configured for 'git push':
    TOMCAT pushes to TOMCAT (up to date)
    master pushes to master (up to date)

 git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: https://github.com/doctorleff/TR.git
  Push  URL: https://github.com/doctorleff/TR.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
    TOMCAT tracked
    master tracked
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    master merges with remote master
  Local refs configured for 'git push':
    TOMCAT pushes to TOMCAT (up to date)
    master pushes to master (up to date)

 git status
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   IncomeFile.java
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
git checkout -- IncomeFile.java
 git checkout TOMCAT
Switched to branch 'TOMCAT'
 git status
# On branch TOMCAT
nothing to commit, working directory clean

 VI IncomeFile.java
git commit -m "changed mC to Mc"
# On branch TOMCAT
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   IncomeFile.java
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
 git add IncomeFile.java
 git commit -m "changed mC to Mc"
[TOMCAT 7b842b0] changed mC to Mc
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
push origin
fatal: The current branch TOMCAT has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin TOMCAT

git push --setu-upstream origin TOMCAT
Username for 'https://github.com': doctorleff
Password for 'https://doctorleff@github.com': 
Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects:  33% (1/3)   
Compressing objects:  66% (2/3)   
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3)   
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects:  33% (1/3)   
Writing objects:  66% (2/3)   
Writing objects: 100% (3/3)   
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 323 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas:   0% (0/1)   remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (1/1)   [K
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (1/1), completed with 1 local object.[K
To https://github.com/doctorleff/TR.git
   ff102ee..7b842b0  TOMCAT -> TOMCAT
Branch TOMCAT set up to track remote branch TOMCAT from origin.
 git add IncomeFile.java
"change M[KCa to aC"
[TOMCAT 1a6739c] change Ca to aC
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
 git push origin
Username for 'https://github.com': doctorleff
Password for 'https://doctorleff@github.com': 
Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects:  33% (1/3)   
Compressing objects:  66% (2/3)   
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3)   
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects:  33% (1/3)   
Writing objects:  66% (2/3)   
Writing objects: 100% (3/3)   
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 324 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas:   0% (0/1)   [K
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (1/1)   Resolving deltas: 100% (1/1), completed with 1 local object.[K
To https://github.com/doctorleff/TR.git
   7b842b0..1a6739c  TOMCAT -> TOMCAT
```

THUS, I then tried to go back to one of the repositories that was corrupted.

```
cd sv/web/src
 git status
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#LONG LIST OF FILES REMOVED for clarity
#
#   Test.java

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
 git add Test.java
 git commit -m "testing with Test.java"
[master (root-commit) 96c329f] testing with Test.java
 1 file changed, 70 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 Test.java origin
fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin master

git push --set-upstream origin master
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists

____________________________________________

git status

# On branch master

# Untracked files:

#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

#

#   $

#   .RatingEntryServletNew.java.swp

#   11in35tr.xls

#   AdminFrontServlet.class

#   AdminFrontServlet.java

#   AgreementBackend.class

      -- REST OF LONG LIST OF FILES GIVEN DELETED FOR BREVITY

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

git remote show origin

fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.



Please make sure you have the correct access rights

and the repository exists.

git config --get remote.origin.url

git remote -v

git ls-remote --get-r[Kurl

fatal: No remote configured to list refs from.

git ls-remote --get-url origin

origin
```

---

I also tried the `git check-ignore -v --` on several files on the depository.
This was as suggested in the answer.

It just returns--I assume that means that these files are not affected by
any ignore rule.

____ response to VonC ___

In `sv/web/src` there is a `.git` subdirectory.  `FETCH_HEAD` is zero bytes
`HEAD` syas `refs: refs/heads/master`  That file exists and contains a long
hex code which I assume is a commit code, but I cannot find it at github.com.

The root (`sv`) also has a `.git`  There, `HEAD` says `refs/heads/tomcat`

MY other local reposityory copy
`sw/web/src` also has a `.git`  Its `HEAD` has 
line `ref: refs/heads/master`  But in that case, that file does not exist.

---

As suggested, I did try `git remote -v` on the two repositories in
question.  Here is the output for `sv`

```
git remote -v
githubrepo      https://github.com/doctorleff/u3e.git (fetch)
githubrepo      https://github.com/doctorleff/u3e.git (push)
origin  https://github.com/doctorleff/u3e.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/doctorleff/u3e.git (push)
```

The second `sw` is showing that the repository is hopelessly corrupted:

```
git remote -v
fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /home)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
```

Since then, I have created a new local clone on this repository from github.
I went back and forth between the two branches and everything is OK.
Thus, please consider this matter closed as not reproducable and no longer
a problem for original poster.
~

Comment: Try to make a [MCVE] or something close to MCVE. Can you write a script which clones the repo to a new directory, `check-ignore`s as @VonC suggested, touches some file and then `status` again? Maybe even making a public fork, with removing all the files but a few files in the PDBE folder? I'd be willing to give it a try.

Comment: Is there a .git in sv/web/src?

Comment: OK. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

> I also checked my `.gitignore` and `.git/info/exclude` Nothing in the latter--former does not specify any of the files in question, all `.java`

Double-check with:

```
git check-ignore -v -- PDBE/yourFile
```

Sometime, gitignore rules can come from other sources (like an IDE).

---

The first push of the tomcat branch should be `git push -u origin tomcat`

If a repo is inside another one, it becomes a nested repo: it might not have an origin, while its parent (which includes said nested repo) have:
Do a `git remote -v` in each folder.
You can add a remote origin (in the nested repo folder) with `git remote add origin /url/remote/repo`. Then the push might work better.