# error Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists

Tags: git

I created a project and uploaded it on a centos 6 server. I installed git on server. Then I create a repository on somewhere in server (in directory public_html) with this command
`git init myproject.git --bare`

Then i change permission of git directory with this command

`chown -R git:git myproject.git`

In my local machine I want to clone project:

`ssh://domain.com/myproject.git`

but I get this error:

```
fatal: '/myproject.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: *Could not read from remote repository.* what did you set for remote origin repository? can you check the [remote origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089430/how-can-i-determine-the-url-that-a-local-git-repository-was-originally-cloned-fr)?

Comment: I have been set this for remote origin repository:
ssh://root@domain.com/myproject.git

Comment: ah my bad `ssh://domain.com/myproject.git` this seems, you need to check this url.. since you are using ssh, is your public key registered on the remote server?

Comment: I added public key into this file: ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
Is this correct?

Comment: err, `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` are you refering this on your local machine or the server for the `domain.com`..? adding public key to `authorized_keys` on a machine is telling them to trust the particular public key afaik.  how do you usually authenticate to that `domain.com`? is it running bitbucket server or something else?

Comment: Is your project really located at `/myproject.git` on the remote server? When using an SSH remote, the path is taken as absolute, not relative to the home directory.

Comment: I am referring ~/.ssh/authorized_keys on the remote server. because the remote server is linux. but my local machine is windows.

Comment: yes, myproject.git existed on remote server and it's located under public_html directory

Comment: Most sensible server setups refuse to let you ssh in as root, ever, for any reason. Try not using `root@` at all. Create a less-powerful user. Note that when using ssh access, the top level directory is the user's home directory, *not* the `public_html` directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL isn't correct for the location of your project. When you use `ssh://example.com/myproject.git`, that tells the server to look for the `/myproject.git` directory on the remote server. That is, the path is absolute, not relative, and you're telling Git that the project is in a directory at the root of the file system.

If you want to access a path under the `public_html` directory, you need to specify a different path. If you're logging in to access the user `git`'s `public_html` directory, then you would need to specify something like `ssh://git@example.com/home/git/public_html/myproject.git`. If you're using a different user, specify a different username and home directory instead.