# fatal: remote origin already exists. , fatal: No such remote:

Tags: github, git-push, git-remote

I tried

`git remote add origin https://github.com/rezaee/confusion-last.git`

and got

`fatal: remote origin already exists.`.

Then tried

`git push -u origin master`

but got:

```
warning: redirecting to https://github.com/rezaee/confusion.git/
To http://github.com/rezaee/confusion.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'http://github.com/rezaee/confusion.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

So I tried

`git remote remove https://github.com/rezaee/confusion-last.git`

but got

`fatal: No such remote: 'https://github.com/rezaee/confusion-last.git'`.

How is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible because [`git remote remove`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote#Documentation/git-remote.txt-emremoveem) looks for a remote alias *name*, *not* the actual URL.

```
git remote remove origin
```

That would have worked.

However, your remote is already set to another URL ([see `git remote -get-url origin`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32991784/6309)).
To change it *without* having to remove it:

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/rezaee/confusion-last.git
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try below git commands:

After git initialization you can add the repo and then try set the url from the git site by below command

```
git remote set-url origin
```

Once origin set try your repo url

```
git remote set-url origin [https: your repo link from git]
```

Check whether the url you set are present inside the master or not

```
git remote -v
```

Now you can push your repo to github

```
git push -u origin master
```

Sometimes set-url works when add don't, so try these above commands.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this each of these commands does and how it solves the problem, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues.