# Is there a way to determine if my local clone is a fork of some github repo?

Tags: git, github, git-clone, git-fork

More specifically, how do I tell if the origin of the repo on disk is a fork of some repo? I am thinking that it should be some API call, but I am not sure. Can I rely on "remote.upstream.url"?

Comment: I suppose that you should have matching commit IDs at the beginning of your local branch(es).

Comment: do `git config --get remote.origin.url`

Comment: This will tell me if the local repo is a clone. It does not tell me if the remote.origin.url is itself a fork.

Comment: Could someone please add typical responses for the two cases fork and clone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [GitHub API for Repositories](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos) to [get a specific repo](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#get)

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo
```

(you can use a [`curl` call from command line](https://gist.github.com/joyrexus/85bf6b02979d8a7b0308))

The JSON answer will include a "`fork`" field: value true or false.

---

Another approach, using the GitHub CLI [`gh repo view`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_view) command:

```bash
gh repo view VonC/git-cred --json isFork
{
  "isFork": false
}
```

Comment: AHA! I can ask MY repo what is it is a fork of. So :owner/:repo comes from `git config --get remote.origin.url`, looking for `"fork": true` and `"full_name:"` in `"parent"`. Thank you.

Comment: @mpersico Exactly. Or, as I mention in https://stackoverflow.com/a/32991784/6309, `git remote get-url origin`.

Comment: AHA2! I’ll be updating with this gem today. I try to read the release notes every time my machine gets a new git package but sometimes I miss it.

Answer (score -4):

Yes, do this:

```
(meta_learning) brandomiranda~/proverbot9001 ❯ git config --get remote.origin.url
git@github.com:brando90/proverbot9001.git
```

Comment: This will tell me if the local repo is a clone. It does not tell me if the remote.origin.url is itself a fork.