# What does it mean when a Github repo is in a given user's account?

Tags: github, git-fork

I want to use `react-native-screens`, and found the repo at https://github.com/kmagiera/react-native-screens. What is the connection between kmagiera and react-native-screens? Does it just mean that kmagiera is the account that created and maintains react-native-screens? When I've seen someone fork a React Native component and say "I fixed this bug, check out my forked repo", the repo is of a similar format: https://github.com//. So, how do I know that https://github.com/kmagiera/react-native-screens is the repo I should pull from, since it could just be kmagiera's forked copy, and there could be multiple such copies?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to determine if my local clone is a fork of some github repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58595716/is-there-a-way-to-determine-if-my-local-clone-is-a-fork-of-some-github-repo)

Answer (score 0):

Forked repos will have the text "forked from ***" under the title when you go to the main page. From that you can get the original repo. Sometimes people announce to use their own fork if the maintainers of the original haven't been maintaining and merging pull requests to the main repo.