# How can I get remote GitHub URL in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

I use GitHub in Android Studio, I pull a project from GitHub using URL.

At present, I hope to copy the URL of the GitHub project, but I find the URL can not be copied, you can see Image 1.

How can I get the GitHub URL of the project in Android Studio?

**Image 1**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can view the remote links in Android Studio as:

1. In menu, click VCS => git => remotes

[image]

2. Then you can copy(select any remote url + cmd/ctrl + C), add, delete or edit the remote url:

[image]

Alternately, you can get the complete details in terminal using

• [git remote show origin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4089452/4936904)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the easier way (less typing):

```
$ git remote -v
```

You can add to your profile with: `alias s='git remote -v && git status'`

Answer (score 0):

It Android Studio, in the bottom bar where the LogCat is, there's another window named **Terminal** open it, and the type:

> git config --get remote.origin.url

The URL will be displayed and you can copy it from there

Comment: Thanks! your way works well , but is there more simple way?