# How do I loop over all my git repos and get their urls to clone later?

Tags: bash, git

I want to transfer all my git repos to another computer. How can I loop over my `~/Sites` directory and get their clone urls/origins?

Comment: This is a very specific problem...

Comment: So is this a duplicate of "how to write a loop in bash" or "how to get a list of remote URLs from a Git repository"? Or "how to change directory without having to change back"?

Comment: how to get a list of remote URLs from a Git repository, I haven't seen any answers on SO

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I determine the URL that a local Git repository was originally cloned from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089430/how-can-i-determine-the-url-that-a-local-git-repository-was-originally-cloned-fr)

Comment: @jonrsharpe no. please read my question. I want all the clone urls in my Sites dir. not just a single one

Comment: So what? You said above that was the specific part you were asking. As mentioned there are multiple parts to the problem, all with existing dupes. We don't need a Q&A for every possible combination of looping over directories and doing a thing, it's up to each of us to decompose the problem, research each part and integrate the answers.

Answer (score 1):

```
for dir in *; do
  ( cd "${dir%/*}" && echo "git clone $(git config --get remote.origin.url)" )
done
```

Comment: I think he just wants the URLs for now, so you don't need the clone - `for d in *; do ( cd $d && git config --get remote.origin.url ); done`