# Vim Autoindent Whitespace

Tags: vim, whitespace

I'm trying to work with Vim as an editor, but when I use the autoindent feature, it deletes my indents that have no text on them. This is really annoying. It's documented to do this too.

Is there a way to stop it from doing this?

Also, this is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000842/autoindent-in-vim-always-empty-the-line-if-there-are-only-whitespace-in-it-can-i) as that simply works around the problem.

Comment: You might check out the `preserveindent` and `copyindent` options. I could not get them to work though. I think usually programmers leave out trailing whitespace for historical version control reasons, to have a standard for newlines as to minimize diff creations, and because they're obsessive complusive (myself included). If you're not doing serious editing, perhaps Kate's vim input mode would be an option.

Comment: I've tried both of those. I may have to patch the code. :l

Comment: Why exactly is it annoying?  I mean, is it just that it's different from what you expected?  Or is it affecting your use negatively in some way, and if so, how?  (I ask because adjusting your use of Vim so the autoindent behavior becomes unnoticeable seems preferable to wasting time on a patch, especially when there are good reasons to avoid lines that have whitespace only. . . )

Comment: @Herbert I don't know about the asker, but I do find it annoying that when I hit `Ctrl+O` from insert mode to paste something on a blank but indented line, the indent disappears.

Comment: If I'm indented and I want to go down two lines and do some more code, to separate portions of the code, I need the blank line in between to be indented. Yes, 'need'. OCD.

Comment: @gatoatigrado -- Doing <space><bs> before the paste solves that problem, and could be made part of a mapping.

Comment: @Jookia -- Why does adding `I` to cpoptions and arrowing down not solve your problem?  `set cpoptions+=I`.

Comment: @gato.. : alternatively `ctrl-F` in insert mode will reindent line to previous indent, so you could do `<ctrl-O>p<ctrl-F>` (and/or create mapping to use `<ctrl-F>` if you wanted).

Comment: I just tried all these things in the Vim IRC, the only workaround seems like a hacky remapping to my enter key. I think I'ma go shop for different editors.

Comment: Ugh, I'll just do the hacky thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following to you .vimrc:

```
inoremap <CR> x<BS><CR>
```

Vim will not eliminate the indent if you type anything at all in a line, even if you delete what you typed right away. This is what the mapping does.

[This](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Get_the_correct_indent_for_new_lines_despite_blank_lines) page suggests another, more elaborate approach for tackling your request. But frankly I think you should adopt Vim's default behaviour of not indenting empty lines. It's The Right Way to generally avoid lines with nothing but whitespace.

Comment: Good advice.  Almost all of Vim's features, including the behavior in question, are well thought out.

Comment: That fixes it, but I've discovered autoindent converts three spaces in to a tab and a space due to my tabstop being 2. So I guess it's out of the question now.

Comment: Jookia -- You want to make sure your `shiftwidth` and `tabstop` settings are the same.  (It appears your `shiftwidth` is now 3 and your `tabstop` is now 2.) You may also want to investigate `expandtab` option, which would ensure that all indented whitespace uses spaces and not tabs.