# How to paste correctly when autoindent in vim resets the line if nothing typed

Tags: vim, indentation, copy-paste, auto-indent

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000842/autoindent-in-vim-always-empty-the-line-if-there-are-only-whitespace-in-it-can) describes how auto indent is ignored with empty lines, using his/her example:

```
....{
....█
....}
```

becomes

```
....{
█
....}
```

when no text is entered. Apparently this is supposed to prevent having indented blank lines. Problem is it interferes with my ability to paste words/lines properly. If I yank a word (lets say 'aardvark'), if I paste on the first line, I get

```
....{aardvark
....}
```

and if I press 'o' then 'p' to paste on the second line, I get

```
....{
aardvark
....}
```

when what I really want is

```
....{
....aardvark
....}
```

I have a similar problem pasting lines two lines down.

Comment: Not really an answer here. I just think you may want to press V to select the whole line and press = to rearrange the indention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you'll like to use <kbd>o</kbd><kbd>CTRL-R</kbd><kbd>"</kbd> instead of <kbd>o</kbd><kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>. See `:help i_CTRL-R`, `:help registers`

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I'll just map it to a key as it is quite the chore to hit the combinations `o` `CTRL` `R` `SHIFT` `"`

Answer (score 0):

Yank lines, then press `]p` instead of `p`.

Comment: That only works when applied **from** an indented line, If you yank a word and want to paste it indented one line below, or yank a line and want to paste it two lines below, `]p` won't work.