# vim removes indentation from the current line

Tags: vim

Every time I enter the Insert mode in vim using `A` and press Enter to go to the next line, `vim` automatically removes all indentation from the current line. For instance, ideally, it should be like this -

```
14   echo $sample;   
15   $ai = system("python ai.py " + $sample, $retVal);
```

If I press `A` on line 15 and then `<CR>`, this is what my vim looks like -

```
14   echo $sample;   
15 $ai = system("python ai.py " + $sample, $retVal);
16
```

This is my .vimrc -

```
"General
set nu      " Set line numbers
set hlsearch    " Set search highlight
set shiftwidth=2
set tabstop=2

"Pathogen
execute pathogen#infect()
call pathogen#helptags()
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on

"ConqueTerm
command Cterm split | ConqueTerm bash
nnoremap <silent> sh :Cterm<CR>

"NerdTree - 
"Fs open Nerdtree on the same tab. Nfs opens NerdTree in new tab.
command Fs NERDTree
command Nfs tabedit | NERDTree
nnoremap <silent> fs :Fs<CR>

"TagBar
nnoremap <silent> tt :TagbarToggle<CR>

"Omni Completion
filetype plugin on
filetype indent on
inoremap <C-Space> <C-X><C-o>

"Editor 
command Ide NERDTree | TagbarToggle

"Move between split windows
nmap <silent> <A-Up> :wincmd k<CR>
nmap <silent> <A-Down> :wincmd j<CR>
nmap <silent> <A-Left> :wincmd h<CR>
nmap <silent> <A-Right> :wincmd l<CR>

"Drag words like in Windows
nnoremap <C-Left> b
vnoremap <C-S-Left> b
nnoremap <C-S-Left> gh<C-O>b
inoremap <C-S-Left> <C-\><C-O>gh<C-O>b

nnoremap <C-Right> w
vnoremap <C-S-Right> w
nnoremap <C-S-Right> gh<C-O>w
inoremap <C-S-Right> <C-\><C-O>gh<C-O>wA

" Start Syntastic in passive mode
let g:syntastic_mode_map = { 'mode': 'passive' }
nnoremap <silent> ch :SyntasticCheck<CR>
```

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: This is by design. Instead, don't worry about lines being empty. Let vim restore the indent position for you when you start editing the line: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6029815/85371

Comment: What type of file are you editing?  If it is PHP, do you have an opening `<?php` at the top?  What does `:verbose set ft? indentexpr` tell you?

Comment: @benjifisher Yes, it's PHP and I have the tags. It's also happening in HTML/JS file. Here's the output from the commmand -  
filetype=php
        Last set from /usr/share/vim/vim73/filetype.vim
  indentexpr=GetPhpIndent()
        Last set from /usr/share/vim/vim73/indent/php.vim

Comment: Do you get the problem near the PHP tag or only later down?  Perhaps vim is confused about whether it is in a PHP block.  Let's stick with just one type of file.

Comment: @benjifisher It happens everywhere in the file.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to set autoindent in your vimrc file:

```
:set ai
```

You can also verify if *autoindent* was previously set (for example through the filetype plugins) by checking its value with

```
:set ai?
```

Comment: He already has `:filetype plugin indent on` in his vimrc file.  That invites filetype-specific indent plugins to override `'ai'` and related options set in his vimrc file.  See `:help 30.3` in the vim  users' manual for an introduction.