# VIM: Inserting New Line then Pressing Escape Moves Cursor to Beginning of Line

Tags: vim, vi

When I am editing a python file, after I insert a new line then press `<ESC>`, the cursor moves all the way to the beginning of the line (ie. column 0). How do I stop this behavior? It's really annoying when I want to paste something on the new line.

Here are my relevant .vimrc settings:

```
set softtabstop=2
set expandtab
set shiftwidth=2
set smartindent
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000842/autoindent-in-vim-always-empty-the-line-if-there-are-only-whitespace-in-it-can

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your goal is to paste something on the new line after just starting it using `o` or `O`, you do not have to enter normal mode for it.

Just type `Control-R "` to paste from the default register directly from insert mode.

More generally, you can type `Control-R <RegisterName>` to paste from that register from insert mode.

Comment: Special case: if you copied something from OUTSIDE OF VIM, you can use `Control-R +` to past from the system clipboard.

Answer (score 1):

If you edit the line (e.g. by pressing <kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Backspace</kbd>) before pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> then Vim will leave the indentation intact.

Answer (score 1):

From normal mode, a quick `==` will indent the line to whatever position it should be at using your indentation settings. At least, that's how it's working for me. My relevant indent section in my vimrc:

```
if has("autocmd")
  filetype plugin indent on
endif
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add mapping so when the auto indentation is triggered a single character is inserted and then deleted:

```
:nnoremap o ox^H
:nnoremap O Ox^H
:inoremap <enter> <enter>x^H
```

`^H` **must** be introduced by pressing <kbd>ctrl+v</kbd><kbd>ctrl+h</kbd>.
So do not copypaste.

Comment: I'd just use <BS> instead of ^H, myself. Much clearer and no special instructions needed to enter it.

Answer (score 1):

If you already pressed <kbd>Esc</kbd> or are coming back to the line later, it is very easy to get the indent back for editing or pasting.

Just use <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> to edit the line, re-applying the automatic indent and landing you in insert mode. Then you can start typing or use <kbd>CTRL+R</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> for example to paste from the system clipboard from the current cursor position.

Note Vim will remove the indent again if you stop editing the line without entering any text. This is intentional as it prevents wasteful trailing whitespace littering the file.