# Blank line rule at the interactive prompt

Tags: python, command-prompt, interactive

Why is there a different rule for blank lines in Python between the interactive prompt and when the program is run from shell as an executable?

Since blank lines are ignored, I enjoy using them abundantly. However, in the interactive prompt, a blank line is used to terminate a loop. Thus, I keep running into indentation errors when I paste a chunk of code into the interactive prompt as I would have blank lines throughout my loops. Consequently, this makes the interactive debugging/development process somewhat tedious. Putting a # instead of blank line helps, but I like my blank lines.

Even more annoying is different behavior between prompts (e.g., the Python shell and [IPython](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPython)). Where the Python interactive prompt would give me an error where I expect it, IPython would keep executing the indented code as if it was not part of loop without complaining.

I feel there is an easy solution out there, but I'm not aware of it. I am using [vi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi) for editing and Python/IPython prompts.

Comment: The thing is, the prompt needs *some* way to determine where your input ends, and a blank line is by far the simplest way (least hassle) for that.

Comment: You may be interested in using an editor, such as Emacs, that can communicate with the interactive Python interpreter. Then you can just select a chunk of code in a scratch buffer and execute it en masse.

Comment: a workaround is to put at least one space on the blank lines inside blocks in your code.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. @jsbueno, for whatever reason, this does not work for me.

Comment: Related: *[Python indentation in "empty lines"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727988/python-indentation-in-empty-lines/2728019#2728019)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) defines how blank lines should be used:

> Blank Lines
>
> Separate top-level function and class definitions with two blank lines.
> Method definitions inside a class are separated by a single blank line.
>
> Extra blank lines may be used (sparingly) to separate groups of related
> functions.  Blank lines may be omitted between a bunch of related
> one-liners (e.g. a set of dummy implementations).
>
> Use blank lines in functions, sparingly, to indicate logical sections.
>
> Python accepts the control-L (i.e. ^L) form feed character as whitespace;
> Many tools treat these characters as page separators, so you may use them
> to separate pages of related sections of your file.  Note, some editors
> and web-based code viewers may not recognize control-L as a form feed
> and will show another glyph in its place.

If you stick to the PEP, the only instance in which blank lines might generate problems in the interactive console are "blank lines in functions to indicate logical sections", I believe.

You can circumvent the problem like this though:

```
>>> def a():
...     print 'foo'\
...
...     print 'bar'
...
>>> a()
foo
bar
```

Note that using `\` instead of `#` as you suggest in your question leaves the blank line... blank (as the `\` goes on the *previous* line).

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the issue. I am able to workaround by using a #, and \ would work as well, as you suggested.

Comment: @IRO-bot The difference with `#` is that if you only have an extra white line, you can put the ` \ ` on the **previous** line (i.e. leaving the following line totally blank. With `#` you can't.

Comment: Thanks! It does help to some extent - good thing to know. I wasn't really looking for a workaround that would alter a feature of the language - but more of a text editor/interpreter trick to circumvent this. Anyways, I find it most convenient for now to just use # instead of blank lines - your solution would get me in trouble when I remove the blank line later on - would have to remove the \ as well.

Comment: @IRO-bot - Good on you, and tanks for the selection as accepted! ;)

Comment: I like Python.  But.  This annoying misfeature - i.e. incompatible syntax between interpreted and batch mode - frustrates both experienced and novice pythoners.  It's obvious that pasting the same correct code into the SAME program that interprets the scripts should get the same effect, yet python continues to defy this expectation even into 3.4.  Considering that virtually every Python programmer I've worked with was startled by this behavior (many switching to IPython to avoid it), it's incomprehensible that the core Python team hasn't bothered to clean this up.

Answer (score 5):

> ...why is there a different rule for blank lines in Python between interactive prompt and when the program is run from shell

Because, the interpreter tries to execute as soon as you hit return, but it needs the blank line to know your function, loop, if statement or other indented block is finished. If writing a function, it doesn't need (in fact won't work) if you add blank lines before the last line of the function. In this case, the blank line is needed to signal the end of the function.

You can execute a script with no blank lines from the shell, for example

```
for i in range(3):
    print i
a = 1000
print a
```

Would produce

```
$ python test.py
0
1
2
1000
```

But if you paste this in the interpreter, you'll get

```
>>> for i in range(3):
...     print i
... a = 1000
  File "<stdin>", line 3
a = 1000
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> print a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

If you add a blank line to signify the end of the loop

```
for i in range(3):
    print i

a = 1000
print a
```

and paste it in the interpreter,

```
>>> for i in range(3):
...     print i
...
0
1
2
>>> a = 1000
>>> print a
1000
```

And that blank line must be blank, even spaces (perhaps auto added by your editor) will cause the interpreter to fail.

If you want to paste a class into the interpreter, then you don't want any spaces between any lines, including between methods. This raises a conflict with PEP8, however, meaning, you can either comply with PEP8, or be interpreter compatible, but not both.

Thus, if you want to be able to copy and paste your code into the standard python interpreter, you'll need a slightly different set of rules.

- Surround top-level function and class definitions with two blank
  lines.
- A blank line is required for top level module code (outside a function or class) to end an indented block, such as a for loop, try/except or if statement.
- Blank lines may not be used within a function, class or method (barring \ or #).

Stick to those and you'll retain the ability to paste into the interpreter. For a class, however, you won't be strictly PEP8 as a blank line [is required](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#blank-lines) before and after a method.

Comment: Indeed. This is a very clear explanation, thanks. At the time of asking the question, I was just beginning with Python. Used ipython exclusively since. The behavior of the standard Python interpreter to parse code line by line is an anti-feature IMO.

Comment: Sure. I just was curious as to how to keep my files interpreter-compatible, and ended up on this question. In the end, I decided to answer it :-)

Answer (score 1):

IPython v5 now handles indented blank multilines just fine:

http://blog.jupyter.org/2016/07/08/ipython-5-0-released/

From the above blog post:

> The prompt_toolkit package is an amazing library from Jonathan
> Slenders and recently reached version 1.0. Going beyond readline,
> prompt_toolkit provides many advanced features for editing text in the
> terminal that significantly improve the user experience. Since it is a
> cross-platform library, all our users on Linux/Unix, macOS and Windows
> benefit from these improvements. Thanks to prompt_toolkit, IPython now
> supports:
>
> - Syntax highlighting as you type
> - Real multi-line editing (up and down arrow keys move between lines)
> - Multi-line paste without breaking indentation or immediately executing code
> - Better code completion interface (we plan to improve that more)
> - Optional mouse support

Comment: Thank you - this is an amazing, very helpful new feature!

Comment: The link is (effectively) broken. It redirects to a generic page.

Comment: OK, the OP has [left the building](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/979:_Wisdom_of_the_Ancients): *"Last seen more than 1 year ago"*

Answer (score -1):

If you are developing on a Unix system, use Sed!

To get rid of all the blank lines before you paste your code into an interactive prompt, use this command:

```
sed '/^$/d' mysourcefile
```

Sed is a stream editor. Here, it takes mysourcefile as an input and then sends the edited text to stdout. Copy and paste the output to the interactive Python shell, and you should be good to go!

(Or use Screen to send the edited source to another screen session with the interactive shell open!)

Comment: loops and if statements will fail