# Why does command line Python require an empty line separating an "if" statement that follows a "while" statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax

I am running Python3 in terminal, copy/pasting my code line by line. In the follow code chunk example (finds median of two sorted arrays):

```
nums1=[1,2]
nums2=[3,4]
output_list = []
while(nums1 and nums2):
    if nums1[0] <= nums2[0]:
        output_list.append(nums1.pop(0))
    else:
        output_list.append(nums2.pop(0))
if nums1:
    output_list.append(nums1.pop(0))
if nums2:
    output_list.append(nums2.pop(0))
```

Upon copy/pasting this into terminal, I get

```
>>> nums1=[1,2]
>>> nums2=[3,4]
>>> output_list = []
>>> while(nums1 and nums2):
...     if nums1[0] <= nums2[0]:
...         output_list.append(nums1.pop(0))
...     else:
...         output_list.append(nums2.pop(0))
... if nums1:
  File "<stdin>", line 6
    if nums1:
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>     output_list.append(nums1.pop(0))
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    output_list.append(nums1.pop(0))
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>> if nums2:
...     output_list.append(nums2.pop(0))
```

This disappears if I have an empty line between the while, and two if statements. Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to PEP8: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#blank-lines

> Blank Lines

Separate top-level function and class definitions with two blank lines. Method definitions inside a class are separated by a single blank line.

Extra blank lines may be used (sparingly) to separate groups of related functions. Blank lines may be omitted between a bunch of related one-liners (e.g. a set of dummy implementations).

Use blank lines in functions, sparingly, to indicate logical sections.

Python accepts the control-L (i.e. ^L) form feed character as whitespace; Many tools treat these characters as page separators, so you may use them to separate pages of related sections of your file. Note, some editors and web-based code viewers may not recognize control-L as a form feed and will show another glyph in its place.

A blank line signifies the end of a loop on then interactive window

For more reference: [Blank line rule at interactive prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8391633/blank-line-rule-at-interactive-prompt/41988906)

Answer (score 1):

This is likely due to the IDE that you're using. I would try to replace the indentation with 4 spaces in terminal, or save the python file to your computer, cd to it's location and run a python3 (put file name ending in .py here) command.