# Indenting multiple lines leaves out blank lines an cause IndentationError

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm on python, VS Code, Mac. When trying to indent multiple lines by selecting them and pressing 'tab', the blank lines are not indented, resulting in "IndentationError" from python. (In the picture below, you can see that the three dots are missing at the blank line, indicating that indenting multiple lines did not work for the blank line. How do I indent multiple lines without causing an IndentationError?

[image: indentation by multiple lines selected and 'tab' causing IndentationError]

Comment: Enable `Indent Using Spaces` and convert existing file using `Convert Indentation to Spaces` command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VS Code, like most other Python editors, is for editing Python files rather than for preparing things for pasting into an interactive session.

When the Python process executes a .py file it does not regard blank lines as ending indents, that is only a feature of the interactive mode so it can know when to execute the indented block.

More information about the difference between handling blank lines in interactive and scripts can be found in this question: [Blank line rule at interactive prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8391633/blank-line-rule-at-interactive-prompt)

Just don't use blank lines in your functions if you want to use them in an interactive prompt.

Comment: Uhu! did not know this, but it makes perfect sense. I stopped using the Jupyter interactive interpreter which is prob why this issue seemed to "appear" today!

Answer (score 0):

Are your vscode and Python extensions the latest version? This is not the case in the latest version.

This may also be related to the way you operate

1. select the code,
2. and then use the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to run the code in the interactive terminal.

[image]

Comment: Everything is up to date, I was not using the interactive terminal since the jupyter kernel couldn't connect and I got fed up with dealing with it. Sorted now though :)